# Null check operator used on a null even if the ? is already added

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 2 newbie questions here.

1st question: Why it won't go through the statement `print('it will NOT go here.');`

I got the error `Null check operator used on a null value`. But I already added `?` to say that it can be null in the `Price?` class.

2nd question: Why this statement `if (_price != null)` shows `The operand can't be null, so the condition is always true.` But I know that it can be null since it is possible that it is not existing. Please help me understand what's going on. Thanks!

This is my code:

```
DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> docRefPrice =
db.collection('dataPath').doc('ThisIsNotExisting'); 
print('it will go here - 1'); 
final DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> documentSnapshotPrice = await docRefPrice.get(); 
print('it will go here - 2'); 
Price? _price = Price.fromFirestore(documentSnapshotPrice); 
print('it will NOT go here.'); 
if (_price != null) { 
  print('_price is not null'); 
} 
else { print('_price is null'); 
  return false; 
}
```

Edit add `fromFirestore`:

```
  factory Price.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc) {
    Map data = doc.data()!;

    return Price(
      price1: data['text1'],
      price2: data['text2'],
    );
  }
```

This is the link that I tried to understand: https://dart.dev/codelabs/dart-cheatsheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first question, the function `fromFirestore` is what's causing the error, add the code for it to your question.

the second question, `_price` won't be null cause `Price.fromFirestore(documentSnapshotPrice);` is a constructor so it will return a `Price` object and never null.

**Edit**

Most probably this line is the reason for the error: `Map data = doc.data()!;` remove the `!` and make the `Map` nullable and handle this case

I will need the `Price` class code to write the code but here is the idea

```
factory Price.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> doc) {
Map? data = doc.data();

return Price(
  price1: data == null ? null : data['text1'], // price1 must accept null in this case
  price2: data == null ? null : data['text2'], // price2 must accept null in this case
);
}
```

Comment: I have added it. In that case, the `fromFirestore` should have the checking if it is null?

Comment: I'm still lacking the understanding. I thought I already understand but it still won't proceed. I tried to add `?` on the `fromFirestore`, but still haveing the same error.

Comment: I edited the answer, feel free to ask if there is anything you don't understand

Comment: Hi, your suggestion works. But the Price class has a lot of fields. Not just price1 and price2. I tried to add `?` on `DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>` but it still won't work. Is that not possible so that I don't need to check the fields 1 by 1 if it is null?

Comment: Anyways, thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.